# не работает программа в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

я начал учить PyQt5, но при запуске у меня ничего не получается, то есть окно просто не появляется.
вот код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class App_PyQt(QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv())

        self.w = QWidget()
        self.w.resize(300, 300)
        self.w.move(300, 500)
        self.w.setWindowTitle("Example")
        self.w.show()

        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())


Main_Window = App_PyQt()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас лишние скобки после `sys.argv`. Уберите их, и все заработает

```
class App_PyQt(QApplication):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        self.w = QWidget()
        self.w.resize(300, 300)
        self.w.move(300, 500)
        self.w.setWindowTitle("Example")
        self.w.show()

        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())


Main_Window = App_PyQt()
```

[Если интересно подробнее](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-sys-python/funktsija-argv-modulja-sys/)